# How to read in data from a csv in R located in a shared google drive

Tags: r, dataframe, google-drive-shared-drive

I've had the following attempts.
This first one results in a downloaded file in an obscure location on my hard drive, but it is damaged and unable to open.

```
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
dl <- drive_download(
  as_id("1yNq-CgafF-4gmi96jOII_DgNxxJkDYRB"), path = temp, overwrite = TRUE)
out <- unzip(temp, exdir = tempdir())
bank <- read.csv(out[14], sep = ",")
```

This next attempt has an issue with file downloading into my R environment.

```
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
download.file("https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1yNq-CgafF-4gmi96jOII_DgNxxJkDYRB&export=download",
              temp)
out <- unzip(temp, exdir = tempdir())
camp_data <- read.csv(out[14], sep = ";")
str(camp_data)
```

I have also tried using the `googledrive` library but have had no luck in accessing the file due to little documentation on the matter (at least in depth). This results in the inability to access the shared drive.

```
camp = shared_drive_get("Campbell")
drive_get(c("Campbell Data.csv", "Campbell Data"), shared_drive = camp)
```

Any tips are appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

First add your google file id as an variable like this:

```
id <- "add_here_your_google_file_id"
```

After that you can use the following code to read the csv:

```
library(utils)
read.csv(sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", id))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get this result that I've gotten before:
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open URL 'https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1qy0VcCGdRnLksaM1IMt2Ra3goG8cv3gT&export=download': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'